# The Role of the Antarctic Circumpolar Vortex & Ocean Current in Keeping Antarctica Frozen

Tags: climate, antarctic, ice, thermodynamics

An offshoot from the question [how does Antarctica stay frozen?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/how-does-antarctica-stay-frozen)

Do the Anatarctic circumpolar vortex and circumpolar ocean current play a role in keeping Antarctica frozen?

Answer (score 2):

The Antarctic Circumpolar Current keeps the warm waters away from the higher latitudes because Antarctica is disconnected from other land masses. This in turn amplifies the westerlies and therefore, polar front Antarctic Circumpolar Current prevent any warmer air/water to enter the high latitudes of Antarctica.[more on this: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Circumpolar_Current)]

During the Oligoncene/Eocene boundary about 32 million years ago, the Tasman Passage opened which gave rise to the onset of Antarctic glaciation [more on this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligocene#The_Drake_Passage)]

Comment: This answer will benefit from some editing and some expansion.